# What does stop somebody from flashing a custom recovery and pulling all user data?

Tags: security, clockworkmod-recovery, privacy, nandroid

For example, I was able to install a Clockworkmod recovery on my Samsung Galaxy Ace 3 phone via Odin and back up all the data in a few clicks.

But if I could do it, what would stop somebody else who could gain access to my phone to do the same and perform a full backup on SD card? Isn't this supposed to be hard to do?

Is encryption the only way to protect private user data?

Comment: Not every device comes with an *unlocked bootloader*. Unlocking a locked bootloader wipes user data. If you're keeping an unlocked device with you, then data theft (and somewhat identity theft) becomes very easy when you lose possession of your device.

Comment: @Firelord OK, thanks. Is it possible to "lock" the bootloader back? (without deleting CyanogenMod)